# How can I add the bibliography in a report with its own section, including number?

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering

I'm writing my thesis as a `report` document using **TeXShop** (`pdflatex` and `bibtex`) and want the bibliography to get its own section number and appear in the table of contents. Here's what I've tried so far and the problems arising:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
```

Does not add the section number, not in the toc and naturally not in the section title.

```
\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand*{\bibname}{\section{References}}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

Error: *! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1.*

```
\cleardoublepage
\section{References}
\renewcommand*{\bibname}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

The only problem this leaves is that this starts the actual bibliography on the next page after it inserts **2.5 References**. Otherwise I would be happy with this solution. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Preliminary remark: In the report class, the bibliography will by default be typeset as an unnumbered *chapter*. If I understand correctly, you do not only want the bibliography to be numbered, but also "downgraded" to a section.

One solution is to selectively change the definition of `\thebibliography`. Add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
  \chapter*{\bibname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}}{%
  \section{References}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

In the main document body, just use

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

I left out `\cleardoublepage` for the sake of consistency (sections do not automatically start a new page).

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much! (And also for correcting the bibilography-typo) :)

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with `natbib`. I've changed natbib.sty (added an option **tocnumber**) to get me a numbered `\section`

Comment: @Pascal: it's not necessary to change **natbib**; all that's needed is to `\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter{\refname}}` or `\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\bibname}}`, depending on the level you want assign the bibliography to.

Comment: @egreg You're absolutely right, thanks for this!

Comment: This does not work on a Report document class does it

Answer (score 1):

I'm still fairly new to Latex and I had the same question. As the provided solution did not work for me (read: I did not fully understand how to implement it), I looked for a different approach that worked better with the general format of my document.

I was already working with `biblatex` so I just changed the heading type for `\printbibliography` and this worked great.
To clarify I'm using the `book` document type with multiple chapters. References are added to each chapter as a separate numbered section, hence the use of `refssection`, so this can be left out.

My sample code:

```
%% preamble
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber, maxbibnames=99, mincitenames=1, giveninits=true, dashed=false, isbn=true, url=false, bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myBiblio.bib}

%% main document
\begin{refsection}
 my text

\printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered]

\end{refsection}
```

Hope this helps some people.

Further suggestions are welcome. As mentioned I'm still new at this as well.