# Making the bibliography appear in the table of contents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, bibliographies

I need to make my (BibTeX) references section appear in the table of contents of my LaTeX document (documentclass: article), with section numbering too.

My approach until now has been making a new section and including the bibliography (`references.bib`) at that point:

```
\section{References}
\bibliography{references}
```

However, the final document shows both the section title that I have written and the section title that BibTeX writes, which is quite redundant and I definitely dislike.

How can I either remove BibTeX's section title, or make the BibTeX bibliography appear in the table of contents without making a new section?

If I were to make the BibTeX bibliography appear in the table of contents without making a new section, how could I assure that the section title that BibTeX writes looks exactly like sections typeset with `\section`?

Comment: The information on this [related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4874/how-can-i-add-the-bibliography-in-a-report-with-its-own-section-including-number) might be useful.

Comment: @Juan: The related question was actually more tricky because it included "downgrading" the bibliography from a chapter to a section.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

As Herbert has hinted, your document class may include options to control the inclusion of the bibliography in the table of contents. For standard classes (`article`, `book`, `report`), adding `\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}` to your document preamble should work. See the [`tocbibind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) documentation for more details.

EDIT: Herbert's suggestion (adding `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}`) may result in an incorrect ToC entry unless the Reference section is forced on a separate page with `\clearpage`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\tableofcontents

\section{foo}

\blindtext[3]

% \clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I want that Bibliography not appears in TOC?

Comment: @hsigrist: This is the default behaviour in many classes.

Comment: The first suggestion is nice (tocbibind), but it changes the name of the section from "References" to "Bibliography". The former is more accurate in my case. Is there a simple way to change it back?

Comment: this: `\settocbibname{References}`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I use `report`. Check out the complete [source](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/latex/x.tex) and the result [document](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/about/degree/x.pdf).

Comment: worked for me only when compiling with Arara not with PDFLateX (Texstudio)

Comment: For me, `\clearpage` caused References to seem to be located on the previous page in TOC. Changed it to `\newpage` and worked like a charm.

Comment: @AkseliPalén for me, with either command, the page number was correct but the link took me to the page before the one with the table of contents. I fixed it with the answer from this relevant question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23499/incorrect-bookmarks-and-page-number-in-table-of-contents

Comment: This work but my bibliography is prefixed by "Chapter 7". How can I remove this ?

Comment: +1 for the `\clearpage` recommendation.

Comment: To avoid numbering the bibliography chapter remove numbib i.e  \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

Answer (score 96):

Using `hyperref`, one should say:

```
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\bibliography{your_bib_archive}
```

Comment: By far the cleanest solution

Answer (score 42):

The following should help, I think:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
```

If you don't want the bibliography to have a chapter number, use the following instead:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
```

Comment: This works indeed, but forces you to use the KOMA classes.

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't be numbered. Use bibliography=totoc instead.

Answer (score 42):

Another simple solution with Biblatex is found at https://fr.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex

```
\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={Whole bibliography}
]

\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=article,title={Articles only}]
```

Answer (score 29):

Here a simple solution for biblatex. Then you can omit the heading and just add a sections as you like.

```
\section{References}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

Comment: This great solution (for biblatex) also helps when using the `nameref` package to do something like `\section{References}\label{sec:references}`, which is then pointed to from the text with "See \nameref{sec:references}".

Comment: `\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={Whole bibliography}]` is neater. See [Making the bibliography appear in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325853/50146)

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{foo}
\nocite{*}% only for demo to get all entries from the bib data file

\let\Section\section 
\def\section*#1{\Section{#1}} 
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{komoedie}

\end{document}
```

It is easier with a class which supports a bib entry in the table of contents, eg. the KOMA-Script classes.

Comment: @Herbert: This will always place the Reference section on a separate page, which may not be appropriate for the article class.

Comment: @lockstep: sure, this is what I prefer. If one want it not start at an own page then deleting of `clearpage` maybe a good idea ... :-)

Comment: @Herbert: Assuming one deletes `clearpage`, could it happen that `\addcontentsline` will point to the wrong page if the Reference section by chance starts a new page? (I dimly remember that I stumbled upon such behaviour once, but I'm not sure about it.)

Comment: @Herbert: I reproduced the problematic behaviour - see my edited answer.

Comment: @lockstep: ah, a competition, I like it :-) No extra answer by me, because it didn't help the one who ask a question ... However: `\let\Section\section` 
`\def\section*#1{\Section*{#1}` 
`\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}}`
`\bibliography{\jobname}`

Comment: @Herbert: If it was a competition indeed, then only because I felt this was one of the few times I had a fighting chance. ;-)

Comment: This solution works fine, but will not number the "References" section, which is something that I require for my document.

Comment: @Genba: see edited code.

Comment: If I want that Bibliography not appears in TOC?

Comment: @hsigrist: then delete the line `\addcontentsline{...`

Comment: Thanks, the `\let...\Section*{#1}` block helped me. What exactely does this macro do?

Comment: @RobW:  `\let\A\B` creates a copy of `\B` named `\A`. If `\B` will be modified later, it doesn't belong to `\A`

Answer (score 0):

I do not like the previous answers because it does not provides you a full control on how the Reference section appears in the table of contents.

If you use `natbib` (that I recommend), simple add one line after the import of the package:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\bibname}}
```

of course you can replace `\section` bu whatever you want: chapter, subsection, etc.

I found this in [this answer to a similar question on the LaTeX.org forum](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9446).

Comment: Downvoted for an over ten years old link. [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib) addresses issues related to `natlib`.`biblatex` adds an option to use `natlib`-like macros for easy switch. Finally in biblatex, the heading options `heading=bibintoc` or `heading=bibnumbered` adds a title in ToC. The former is a non-numbered while the latter is a numbered title. Whether the added title is chapter-like or section-like depends on the document class.

Comment: thank you for the link @Celdor, nevertheless I do not see any information related to how to do this with `natbib`. The link is old because natbib is an old package.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing that worked for me after much trial and error.

```
\usepackage{afterpage}
...
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{toc}{}}
    \tableofcontents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
...
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography

    \afterpage{\phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acronyms}}
    \printglossaries
```