# Incorrect bookmarks and page number in table of contents

Tags: bibliographies, table-of-contents, page-breaking, bookmarks

I have problem with table of contents and with bookmarks. In pdf file

- table of contents shows wrong page number of Introduction and Bibliography,
- Bookmarks: introduction and bibliography don't bring me to the correct page.

Part of my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=false,draft=false,pdfpagelabels=false,pdfstartview=FitH,pdfstartpage=1,bookmarks=true,pdfauthor={LiN},pdftitle={PD},pdfsubject={Titlei},pdfkeywords={words},unicode=true]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\begin{thebibliography}{9999999}%
\bibitem{1}Author, \emph{Title of book}, Publisher.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

How can I change that?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 83):

Put a `\cleardoublepage` before `\addcontentsline`. Also a `\phantomsection` is needed, since you are using **hyperref**:

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter*{Introduction}
```

`\clearpage` gives a wrong result if the Table of Contents has an odd number of pages; `\cleardoublepage` avoids the problem altogether.

Another way is to put `\addcontentsline` *after* `\chapter*{Introduction}`; the same for the bibliography:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9999999}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibitem{1}Author, \emph{Title of book}, Publisher.
\end{thebibliography}
```

The method `\cleardoublepage\phantomsection\addcontentsline` must be used for the lists of figures and tables and for the bibliography if it's done with BibTeX.

Comment: +1 for the \phantomsection which I never knew about, but works perfectly :)

Comment: This is even a problem when using `\secnumdepth` to suppress numbering of something one wants in the toc. It goes in the toc just fine without an `\addcontentsline`, but the links will be all wrong. The best solution I've found for that problem is to `\usepackage{etoolbox} \preto\section\phantomsection` (or whichever sectioning macro is relevant) - this *usually* doesn't break stuff.

Comment: @egreg: I have tried this solution, but gives several problems, please take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187744/wrong-index-numeration-even-though-cleardoublepage-before-addcontentsline-has Thanks.

Comment: The `References` bookmark led to the wrong page for me. Solved the problem putting these two commands just above `\bibliography{}`.

Comment: +1 for the hint that `\cleardoublepage` goes _before_ `\addcontentsline`. I am using the Thesis class from http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis and it works.

Comment: Saved my bacon at the last minute :)

Answer (score 2):

put a `\cleardoublepage` before every `addcontentsline`

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: sorry, should be `\cleardoublepage` for a two sided document

Comment: `\phantomsection` is required as mentioned in egreg's answer.