# Hyperref pointing is incorrect in the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I'm observing strange behavior with `hyperref` and the `\tableofcontents`. Clicking on `List of Tables` or `Synopsis` takes me to the `Preface` page. Perhaps it has something to do with `\chapter*` titles for these sections.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Preface}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\chapter*{Synopsis}
\section{Section Title}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See the similar question and answer here: [Incorrect bookmarks and page number in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23499/incorrect-bookmarks-and-page-number-in-table-of-contents).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `\cleardoublepage\phantomsection` before `\listoftables`.

A `\phantomsection` seems not to be necessary before `\chapter*`. The **amsbook** class is slightly different from **book**, in that it puts *all* chapters, numbered or not, in the table of contents. This also creates correctly the anchors for them, but `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures` don't use `\chapter*` internally and so the anchors for them are not created.

It's also good to load the **bookmark** package after **hyperref**: it simplifies bookmark management.