# Link to bibliography in the ToC fails

Tags: bibliographies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect bookmarks and page number in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23499/incorrect-bookmarks-and-page-number-in-table-of-contents)

I've created a table of contents with links to each chapter and section. I use this package

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=red,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

and I use this for bibliography

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{} bla bla bla
\end{thebibliography}
```

If I click on the item in table of contents, the bibliography's link is wrong: it is linked to the previous page.

How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 12):

This is discussed in the hyperref manual.  Basically hyperref needs an anchor to produce the correct link.   Add `\phantomsection` before `\addcontentsline` to provide one.

Comment: In case you have a two-sided document, you'll also have to add a cleardoublepage. So for me, it looks like this:
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\bibliography{bib}

Comment: Thanks @Prof.Chaos. Most answers relating to this topic seem to be missing this additional piece of information.