# LyX: crossreference keeps popping up in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, lyx

I have a slight problem with LyX in my latest document. I do have a rather large appendix and have inserted titles to structure it a bit. Since my appendix has to be unnumbered I used `\subsubsection*` and inserted an entry for the ToC as well as a label:

```
Ausschnitt 1 
[sub:Ausschnitt-1]

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\numberline{}Ausschnitt\ 1}

\subsubsectionmark{Ausschnitt\ 1}
```

that works fine but the problem is that every time I use a cross-reference to this label the cross-reference itself appears as an entry in the ToC as well.. It doesn't help to move the label to the end, the problem remains the same.

So is there anything I can do to prevent the cross-references from popping up in the ToC?

**Edit**: 
I found the problem or at least parts of it. In some instances it wouldn't let me set the brackets appropriately and I can't get it to work properly.

In LyX, the code looks like this:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\numberline{}Ausschnitt\ 1}
\subsubsectionmark{Ausschnitt\ 1}
```

if I try to submit this, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Too many }'s:  ...tt\ 1}\subsubsectionmark{Ausschnitt\ 1}}}
```

You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.

it lets me generate the pdf if I remove the final bracket but then the problem with all the cross-references popping up in the ToC starts.

is there a way to remove those brackets manually?

Comment: Related to [Incorrect bookmarks and page number in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23503/38350)?

Comment: It's difficult to assess the problem in its current state. What I would suggest is to slowly start trimming the document you've created to try and isolate the problem. It's clear that there are other things going on since your code snippet does not show the ending braces apparent in your error message. So, it's almost up to you to figure it out, since we can't reproduce the problem.