# Change the nomenclature from Chapter to Section

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, nomenclature

How can I change Nomenclature from a chapter to section in a report
I am using

```
\section*{Nomenclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Nomenclature}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{}
\printnomenclature
```

However I have a Chapter with no name in my contents.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\nomname}{}` is redefining `\nomname` to an empty string.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: John, remember that the best way to say thanks over here is to accept the answer you like most. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852). You can also upvote answers (and questions) that you consider useful.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thenomenclature{%
  \section*{\nomname}
  \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
\nompreamble
\list{}{%
\labelwidth\nom@tempdim
\leftmargin\labelwidth
\advance\leftmargin\labelsep
\itemsep\nomitemsep
\let\makelabel\nomlabel}}
\makeatother
```

The original definition begins with

```
\def\thenomenclature{%
\@ifundefined{chapter}%
{
  \section*{\nomname}
  \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
}%
{
  \chapter*{\nomname}
  \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\fi%
}%
}
```

which causes the heading to be typeset as a `\section*` in classes that don't implement chapters and to use \chapter* if the class implements chapters. The redefinition I suggested overrides this forcing the heading to be typeset using `\section*` in all cases.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\makeatletter
\def\thenomenclature{%
  \section*{\nomname}
  \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
  \nompreamble
  \list{}{%
    \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \itemsep\nomitemsep
    \let\makelabel\nomlabel}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%

\section{A test section}
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Very similar to Gonzalo's answer, but here we patch the command `\thenomenclature` so the code to be added in the preamble is lesser.

This is the code you need to add in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\@ifundefined{chapter}}
  {\@ifundefined{relax}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

The test `\@ifundefined{relax}` surely returns true so it works (thanks to egreg for pointing it out).

Full code (partially borrowed by Gonzalo's answer)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\@ifundefined{chapter}}
  {\@ifundefined{relax}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%

\section{A test section}
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `\@ifundefined{relax}` is better than `\@ifundefined{}`; the empty name control sequence *may* be defined, while `\relax` will surely return “undefined”. You can simply do `\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}{chapter}{relax}{}{}`. If one wants something that surely returns “defined”, `\@ifundefined{begin}` should do.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to answer for this myself and indeed either of the proposed answers from Gonzalo and Karlkoeller do work. However, I didn't like the fact that both will modify the nomenclature appearance. So I come up with the following solution: Add "manually" the nomenclature to the TOC instead of using the option instead of using [intoc].

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
  \makenomenclature
  \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}
\end{document}
```

That will keep the nomenclature appearance as:

[image]

I prefer this option to keep the format consistent with the other lists I have such as figures/tables etc. This also works for glossaries: don't use the [section] option but instead do it "manually", for example:

```
\printglossary[title=List of Acronyms,type=\acronymtype]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Acronyms}
```

Comment: Welcome. This does not answer the question. Your nomenclature is still a chapter, not a section. The entry in the toc is of the level section, but it will show the wrong page as soon as your lists are longer than one page.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes I know the nomenclature is still a chapter but enter as a section in the toc but I guess that what I wanted maybe to exactly what @John was looking for. Yes maybe I should have mentioned I put a `\cleardoublepage`  before `\addconentsline` that is why I don't have the problem with the cross-references. Also, a `\phantomsection`  is advisable:
[link] https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23499/incorrect-bookmarks-and-page-number-in-table-of-contents

Comment: If the nomenclature has more than one page, the reference in the TOC will be wrong.

Comment: my is 4pages long and still working fine. I think it's because I put the `\cleardoublepage` before

Comment: The point is, you have to clear the page, add the toc entry and *after* that, you have to print the list. In your example, the complete list is printed and at the end of the list, the entry is made. That is just wrong and an error many beginners do.