# Add section number to Nomenclature in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, nomenclature

I want to have a section number before my Nomenclature, at the moment it looks like this:

[image]

I have used the following code:

```
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
```

I'm working in article style if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159522/90297). I haven't really checked it through, a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/90297) woud have helped.

```
\makeatletter
\def\thenomenclature{%
  \section{\nomname}
  \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
\nompreamble
\list{}{%
\labelwidth\nom@tempdim
\leftmargin\labelwidth
\advance\leftmargin\labelsep
\itemsep\nomitemsep
\let\makelabel\nomlabel}}
\makeatother
```