# Nomenclature Package and Appendices

Tags: appendices, nomenclature, appendix, nomencl

There are a lot of similar posts to this but I have yet to find one that correctly solves my issue. The tl;dr is: How do I make `nomenclature` produce only a list of variables without producing a new chapter?

Long version:

I want to use the `nomencl` package to create a sorted list of variables in the first appendix chapter of my thesis. I am writing in Overleaf.

The appendix package works fine on its own. In my main .tex file, I have

```
\include{introduction}
...
\include{conclusion}
\appendix
\include{appa}
\include{appb}
\include{biblio}
\end{document}
```

My appendix files `appa` and `appb` both start with a chapter title. For example, `appb` begins with `\chapter{Figures}` which displays on the page as

[image: AppendixB on the Page]

and in the table of contents as

[image: AppendixA in ToC]

The nomenclature package on its own works just fine. I define all of my variables and a new chapter containing a list appears where I place `\printnomenclature`. I only want the list though. It should appear on the page as

Appendix A

Nomenclature

(list of nomenclature)

Because `\printnomenclature` starts a new chapter, if I write

```
\chapter{Nomenclature}
\printnomenclature
```

in `appa` I end up with

[image: nomenclature wrong]

with Chapter A: Nomenclature on page 55 and the list actually on page 57. It only appears in the ToC because I included `[intoc]` for the sake of illustration. I want everything to be on page 55 with the page itself appearing like Appendix B did in the first figure. How do I do this?

I tried various solutions from other posts to remove the chapter title on Page 57, but I couldn't find a way to prevent that chapter from being produced itself. As a result, I end up with skipped pages between the chapter title on page 55 and the list on page 57.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `nomencl` makes use of `\chapter*{}` (if available in the class) to create the list of symbols and so a new page is created.

First, load the `nomencl` package with the option `notocbasic` (but not `intoc` otherwise the entry will be duplicated in table of contents), that is,

```
\usepackage[notocbasic]{nomencl}
```

From `nomencl.sty` we find:

```
\makeatletter % added
\def\thenomenclature{%
  \providecommand*{\listofnlsname}{\nomname}%
  \if@nomencl@tocbasic
    \let\list@fname\listofnlsname
    \def\@currext{nls}%
    \tocbasic@listhead{\list@fname}%
   \else
    \@ifundefined{chapter}%
    {
      \section{\nomname}
      \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
    }%
    {
      \chapter{\nomname} %%% <----------- deleted * here
      \@mkboth{\nomname}{\nomname}%
      \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\fi%
    }%
  \fi
  \nompreamble
  \if@nomentbl
    \let\itemOrig=\item
    \def\item{\gdef\item{\\}}%
    \expandafter\longtable\expandafter{\@nomtableformat}
  \else
    \list{}{%
      \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
      \leftmargin\labelwidth
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
      \itemsep\nomitemsep
      \let\makelabel\nomlabel}%
  \fi
}

\makeatother % added
```

and then simply put the code above on your preamble. In the document, you simply use `\appendix` and `\printnomenclature`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. That didn't solve the problem, unfortunately. I added the code to the preamble followed by 
`\usepackage[notocbasic]{nomencl}

\makenomenclature` 

and still have Appendix A: Nomenclature on page 55 and Nomenclature followed by the list on Page 57. What other info can I provide to help?

Comment: The code has to go *after* loading nomencl.sty, because it replaces part of the nomencl definitions.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau, yes, right. I forgot to mention that. I'll edit.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. I also wasn't sure where to place `\makenomenclature`, so I tried both before and after the code block and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: this answer may not apply to your actual needs.

**IF** you want to completely ignore all `\chapter*` commands in your appendices, and do the sectioning yourself, then you can declare

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{\renewcommand\@schapter[1]{}}
\makeatother
```

in your document preamble.

**IF** you want to treat those `\chapter*` declarations as numbered (lettered) chapters (appendices), then the incantation is

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{\renewcommand\@schapter{\chapter}}
\makeatother
```

(The "`*`" is consumed before `\@schapter` goes to work.)

Note that these make assumptions on how the document class defines `\chapter`, so can't be relied on everywhere.

Comment: Welcome Back....happy to see you....

Answer (score 1):

First, add the following to your preamble

```
\makenomenclature
\makeatletter
\def\thenomenclature{%
  \chapter{\nomname}
  \nompreamble
  \list{}{%
    \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \itemsep\nomitemsep
    \let\makelabel\nomlabel}
  }
\makeatother
```

Second and last, add after `\appendix` command the `printnomenclature`.

NB: This is a modification of provided src code at [Change the nomenclature from Chapter to Section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159520/change-the-nomenclature-from-chapter-to-section)