# Change "References" to "references" in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, capitalization, naming

I am producing a simple document of the `report` class, with references produced by BibTeX. I would like to change the "References" text entry in the table of contents to "references", making the text lowercase. Could you suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\bibname}{references}`.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8458/making-the-bibliography-appear-in-the-table-of-contents

Comment: Also possibly helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr

Comment: Can you add some motivation? I don't see why you would be using lowercase in the TOC, unless the title is typeset in small caps.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be answered related to the two linked question in the comments.

1. Add the bibliography to the table of contents: [Making the bibliography appear in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8458/making-the-bibliography-appear-in-the-table-of-contents)
2. rename the title of the bibliography: [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr)