# thebibliography environment

Tags: bibliographies

When I write:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{key1} First item 
\bibitem{key2} Second item 
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The pdf displays "Bibliography" like a title. Can I change it? For example, istead of displaying "Bibliography", displaying "Information sources". Also, can I make it appear in the table of contents?

Here is my full preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\addto\captionscatalan{\renewcommand{\bibname}{Fonts d'informació}}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\parskip=2mm
\makeindex
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993 for the re-naming. For the Table of Content we need your MWE as this depends on the documentclasses.

Comment: Here some suggestions for the appearance in the ToC: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8458

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps a lot. The document class i am using is "report".

Answer (score 1):

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\addto\captionscatalan{\renewcommand*{\bibname}{Fonts d'informació}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{4}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{key1} First item 
\bibitem{key2} Second item 
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But when I change the name from "Bibliografia" to "Fonts d'informació" it does not display the "ó" and it stays "Fonts d'informaci". Also, it now displays Bibliography as a chapter, like: "Capítol 5: Bibliografia". Can I get rid of it like \chapter* would?

Comment: You are not showing us your complete MWE. Just guessing around here. Clearly you have loaded some `babel` with Portuguese or alike. I need this information when I shall help you. About the `ó`: Please read a little bit about font encoding in LaTeX. Do you use pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with this and I don't know what you need. I do use pdfLaTeX, with TeXMaker and MikTeX. Thank you.

Comment: @Nuria See my edit. I think I got you right now. You have to load the utf8 encoding before using an accent for the first time.