# Bibliography properly indexed in ToC but not in PDF

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents

I realised my bibliography was not being included in the ToC, I was taking a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325853/66353
However, while the inclusion of the option `heading=bibintoc` in `\printbibliography` made the trick, in the PDF the link points to a previous section (p. 317 instead of p. 319):

[image]

Are there any options to include it on the PDF correctly. I have been going through https://fr.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex with no luck. Concretely, the call I am making is

```
 \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
```

Please, find below a minimum version of the skeleton (with only the implicated libraries) of the main file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, urldate=long, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}
% Fake bibliography
@article{bergquist2001power,
author = {Bergquist, Magnus and Ljungberg, Jan},
title = {{The power of gifts: organizing social relationships in open source communities}},
journal = {Information Systems Journal},
volume = {11},
number = {4},
publisher = {Blackwell Science Ltd},
issn = {1365-2575},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1046/j.1365-2575.2001.00111.x},
doi = {10.1046/j.1365-2575.2001.00111.x},
pages = {305--320},
keywords = {Gift culture, open source, peer review},
year = {2001}
}

\end{thebibliography}
%% Print index 
\newpage
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} 
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} %to solve issue with appendixes affecting list of figs and tables

\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\listoffigures

%%%%%%%% CHAPTERS %%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter{A}
\lipsum

\chapter{B}
\lipsum
\parencite{bergquist2001power}
\lipsum

\chapter{C}
\lipsum


%%%%%%%% END CHAPTERS %%%%%%%%%


%% Bibliography - define types and non-types to distinguish websites
\newpage
%% Added to include in ToC. Works in object, but not in PDF bookmark
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mhhh, if you don't have other code that is supposed to add the bibliography to the toc, then `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]` should work just fine. Can you reproduce your problem in an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)?

Comment: Have you tried deleting all auxiliary files (`.aux`, ...) and recompile from scratch?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't run your example since we do not have all the files you `\include`. Can you reproduce the issue in a document where you don't use `\include`? See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3343/35864

Comment: Note also that your MWE misses crucial packages. You do not load `hyperref` (which is integral to the question). The command `\onehalfspacing` also needs another package (either drop it in the MWE, or load the relevant package - if it is important, if you can reproduce the issue without it, drop it). Please check your MWE in an empty folder before you submit it to make sure it compiles and actually shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @moewe! I am going through http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html to create a MWE of this case, however, I am not really sure how to deal with the includes. Should I create "dummy" include ones? Otherwise it is not possible to reproduce the error with the index. Thanks!

Comment: Try to have all the text in one file. If it is enough to replace the `\include` by a simple word in the MWE that would be preferable. If you need more text, have a look at the `lipsum` package https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum. Definitely compile the MWE in a new, empty directory and make sure you get no errors and that the compiled document shows the issue at hand.

Comment: Thanks @moewe! Any thoughts on how can I try to create a MWE to include the bibliography. I have tried to embedded as in https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex , but it does not reproduce the same document. I am afraid I could not find any references on how to do this on http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html#x1-70003.1.2 neither. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864 You can also use the file `biblatex-examples.bib` which is available on all installations that have `biblatex` installed.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured out what the issue was here, it is necessary to add a `\phantomsection`. Hence, the code regarding this part goes as follows:

```
\newpage
\phantomsection
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
```

Comment: It should not be necessary to have to resort to a `\phantomsection` with `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]`.