# Section*{} and table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

When using \section*{XXXXXX} it won't show in the table of contents. Is there any way to show this section without a number in the toc?

Comment: This question is also relevant: [Making the bibliography appear in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8458)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{XXXXXX}
\addtocontents{toc}{XXXXXX}

\end{document}
```

Comment: An explanation is is always welcome :)

Comment: Thanks wun, it almost worked --> \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{XXXXX}