# bibliography is displayed twice in doc ( latex )

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning

i use simple method to insert my biblio and webography in my doc :

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[francais]{babel}
    \usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{appendix}
    \usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}
    \usepackage{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption} 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage{float} 
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \floatplacement{figure}{H}

    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

    \makeglossaries
    \lhead{}
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.5pt}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\today}
    \begin{document}
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \listoffigures
    \newpage
    \chapter{ Présentation} 

    \section{introduction}
    \subsection{ exemple2}
.............................
.............................
........
    \chapter*{Conclusion et perspective}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion et perspective}


    \newpage


    \printglossary



    \chapter*{Bibliographie et Webographie}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie et Webographie}
    \begin{thebibliography}{8}
    \bibitem{latexcompanion} 
    Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. 
    \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}. 
    Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

    \bibitem{einstein} 
    Albert Einstein. 
    \textit{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. (German) 
    [\textit{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies}]. 
    Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891–921, 1905.

    \bibitem{knuthwebsite} 
    Knuth: Computers and Typesetting,
    \url{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html},consulter le 23 12 2011.
    \end{thebibliography}

    \chapter*{Annexes}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Annexes}



    \appendix 
    \newpage

    \end{document}
```

when i compil my code I have a result like that :

[image]

please how can not diplay the second bibliographie in my doc i need just the fisrt " bibliographie et webographie"

thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you provide a `MWE` of your content, it will help the experts to help you in a perfect manner...

Comment: thank you but what us the MWE ?

Comment: Please refer the link https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks for more details about `MWE`

Comment: MadyYuvi was referring to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) - please edit your question to add the full code for a small document that shows your problem. The issue is almost certainly in your main .tex file and without it, we can't even begin to guess at the cause.

Comment: (Btw, @MadyYuvi - you probably meant the link I posted above - the one you gave doesn't seem very relevant)

Comment: @MadyYuvi i had edit my question is good now ? thank you

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker now i had edit my question with complet code my doc ! thank you

Comment: Don't typeset the bibliography heading manually. Instead redefine the relevant macros https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/35864. If you want an entry in the ToC have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8458/35864

Comment: @elyacoubymajda `moewe` suggested a good idea, do you solve you problem?

Comment: @MadyYuvi yeah is good now thank you