# Table of content of my paper is showing wrong reference page number

Tags: overleaf

I am new to this LaTeX.

My problem is, the reference page of my paper starts with 11-14. but on the table of content it is showing the last page number 14.
when i'm clicking "reference" on the TOC, it is taking me to the current page which is 11 but on TOC it is written as 14. why? how can i change it?

am using this package `\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}`

```
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{natdin}
    \bibliography{references}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\end{document}
```

**I am using overleaf**

please let me know the problem, submission deadline is almost here!!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If I understand your document setup correctly, the bibliography is four pages long, starts on page 11, and ends on page 14. Does the page numbering problem fix itself if you exchange the order of `\bibliography{references}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}` and rerun LaTeX on the document *twice*?

Comment: wow!! it worked!!!
tried everything except this,, stuck on this for last two days..
thank you so much man...

Comment: Never trust code you find on the internet ;-) If you use a standard document class, the package `tocbibind` may be a better option. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8458/35864.

Comment: as this is my first time.. but next time i will create my own.. 
thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @moewe - Thanks for the vote of confidence. ;-)