# Removing "References" title from bibliography rendering in PDF

Tags: overleaf, bibliographystyle

I try to remove the un-numbered title "References" at the beginning of the bibliography, which is inserted automatically at the start of the list of references. The problem is that it does not enter into the table of contents, unless I declare it as a "\section". Therefore, I made this "\section" right before the calling command for the bibliography

```
\section{References}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bib}
```

but then I get a double "References"

Is there any chance to remove this references title and use my numbered section title? Or alterantively, number that references title and remove my section title?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: You might find an answer here: [Making the bibliography appear in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8458)