# Remove the number before references

Tags: titlesec

The following MWE puts number 2. before References which I am trying to remove. What appears in Chapter 1 and Chapter 2 are correct.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{plain}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\large \bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{16pt}
{\normalsize \thechapter{.}\ }[]

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \chapter{Theory}

\backmatter
    \clearpage
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
    \begin{thebibliography}{10}
        \bibitem{Taylor}{Taylor M. \& Mankiw, N.}, \emph {Economics}, Cengage Learning EMEA, UK (1980)
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are including the chapter number in the chapter heading and the title. So, for `\chapter{Introduction}`, you'll see **Chapter 1 1. Introduction**. This seems odd, yet this is what you want for the first chapters. Are you sure? That's also the reason behind the **2.** being part of the references chapter.

Comment: Yes, it is required like Chapter 1 and again 1. Introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting a solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4879/76279). Not sure if it is the optimal way in your case, but it works. Include the etoolbox package. The patchcmd of thebibliography uses a * on section so that it is not numbered.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\large \bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{16pt}
{\normalsize \thechapter{.}\ }[]

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
  \chapter*{\bibname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}}{%
  \section*{References}}{}{}% use * so that the sec is not numbered.
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \chapter{Theory}

\backmatter
    \clearpage
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
    \begin{thebibliography}{10}
        \bibitem{Taylor}{Taylor M. \& Mankiw, N.}, \emph {Economics}, Cengage Learning EMEA, UK (1980)
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `thebibliography` environment inside the `book` class is set as a `\chapter*`. From [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) (comments added):

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}% <----------- How the bibliography is set
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
```

[`titlesec`](//ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) strongly discourages the use of starred versions for section. From the [`titlesec` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) (section **4.2 Starred versions**):

> Using sectioning commands in the starred version is strongly discouraged. Instead, you can use a set of markup oriented commands which are easy to define and modify, if necessary. Thus, you can test different layouts before choosing amongst them.
>
> Firstly remember if you say
>
> ```
> \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
> ```
>
> sections will be not numbered but they will be included in both ToC and headers.

With this in mind, you can use the following setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\large \bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{16pt}
  {\normalsize \thechapter{.}\ }[]

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Theory}

\clearpage

\backmatter

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}% Number only up to \part
\renewcommand{\thechapter}[2]{}% Gobble {.} and {\ }
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{Taylor}
  Taylor M.\ \& Mankiw, N., \emph{Economics}, Cengage Learning EMEA, UK (1980)
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The two additional commands before called the `thebibliography` environment removes the numbering within the regular `\chapter` sequence, yet still sets it as a `\chapter*`.

Comment: Thank for the explanation. This also works well even when some standard bib style is used e.g. IEEE rather than thebibliography.